# Modify Trackpoint sensitivity in Ubuntu 17.10 (Gnome) on Wayland (Thinkpad X1 Carbon 5th)

Tags: gnome, 17.10, wayland, trackpoint

Does anybody know how to increase the sensitivity of the Trackpoint on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon (5th generation) running with Ubuntu 17.10 Gnome on Wayland? I googled for it but all I found is that the input devices should be managed by `libinput` by default in this setup (Arch wiki). But the package `libinput` is even not installed on my machine.

Running

```
xinput list
```

gives:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

where the properties (`xinput --list-props 6`) look like:

```
Device 'xwayland-pointer:13':
    Device Enabled (119):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (121): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (244): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (245):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (246):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (247):    10.000000
```

Changing values doesn't seem to have an effect.

Xorg sessions are not an option, since I need fractional scaling for a high dpi screen.

In the case, that I have to install the package `libinput`, can anybody provide some information about what to change exactly? Since I'm new to Linux, I would happy to get explanations easy to follow for a beginner.